# EditText.setHint doesn't work when it has content in it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to add a clear function to a button.
I have written this code:

```
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            name.setHint("Enter name");
            mail.setHint("Enter mail");
            num.setHint("Enter num");
        }
    });
```

It works when the field is empty but does not if the field has content in it.

Thank you for your time.
It's not a TextInputLayout. Works well with EditText.setText .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint will only show when the content is empty. So you may clear your content  and set hint at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The hint will not show when there is text inside a text field. You can clear text like below:

```
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            name.setHint("Enter name");
            name.setText("");

            mail.setHint("Enter mail");
            mail.setText("");

            num.setHint("Enter num");
            num.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't worked that way, just added setText before setHint and it worked fine. as @ruby6221 said